# How to use the basic semantic.min.css in Angular?

Tags: angular, semantic-ui

I want to use `semantic.min.css` file in my angular.

[image: pic1]

`favicon.ico` and `semantic.min.css` under the same directory.

[image: pic2]

But the browser still can't get this file.
My question is that why favicon.ico can load but semantic.min.css not, and how to fix that?

Comment: the first picture seems dead. the two files just the under the same directory.

Comment: Note the pictures are now inlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should place static files into assets directory. and if you are using angular-cli then you already have included assets in cli config

```
 "apps": [
    {
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
    }
]
```

Then write your css file into this block

```
  "styles": [
    "/path-to-css/semantic.min.css",
  ]
```

Semantic has css only version try install it through npm https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS, then you can add path to it like:

"styles": [
        "../node_modules/semantic-ui-css/dist/semantic.min.css" //it's not exactly path, fix it
      ],

Comment: thank you vary much! i get this worked. it really helps!

Comment: No problem, accept answer if it was helpful, thanks.